# Range of the Radon Transform

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let us consider the Radon transform in two dimensions:

$$\tag{1}Rf(r,\theta):=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(r\cos\theta-t\sin\theta,r\sin\theta+t\cos\theta) dt,$$

where $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0\leq\theta\leq \pi$. There is a well known theorem about the range of the transform.

**Theorem**. A function $g(r,\theta)$ can be represented as a Radon transform of some function $f(x,y)$ (i.e. $g=R[f]$) if and only if for all integers $n\geq0$
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} r^ng(r,\theta) dr$$ is a homogeneous polynomial of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$.

Obviously, if $g(r,\theta)$ belongs to the range of the Radon transform then the inverse Radon transform of the function $g(r,\theta)$ is $f(x,y)$.

Now let us consider a function which **DOES  NOT** belong to the range of the transform.

**QUESTION:** What we would receive if we apply the inverse Radon transform to a function not 
from the range of the transform?

For example, consider function $g(r,\theta):= e^{-r^2}$ if $0\leq\theta\leq \pi/2$ and 
$g(r,\theta):= e^{-r^2(1-\cos\theta\sin\theta)}$ if $\pi/2\leq\theta\leq\pi$. This function does not belong to the range of the Radon transform. Then, on the one hand, there is no function $f$ such that $g=R[f]$. On the other hand, $g= R[ R^{-1}g ]$.

What's wrong with this paradox?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Let us notice that $R[R^{-1}g]$ is defined correctly, but it is not equal to $g$.

Indeed, if $g=R[R^{-1}g]$, then

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} r^ng(r,\theta) dr = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} r^n R[R^{-1}g] (r,\theta) dr=$$

$$=\int\int r^n [R^{-1}g] (r\cos\theta−t\sin\theta,r\sin\theta+t\cos\theta)drdt=$$

$$=\int\int (u\cos\theta+v\sin\theta)^n [R^{-1}g] (u,v)dudv,$$

which is a homogeneous polynomial of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ (we just have to expand the brackets). On the other hand it is NOT a homogeneous polynomial (by assumption). Therefore $g\neq R[R^{-1}g]$.

Comment: Without specifying the domain of the Radon transform, it does not make sense to talk about its range. My feeling is that this is the root of your supposed paradox

Comment: Yemon, I don't quite understand your comment. f(x,y) is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and Radon transform, $R[f](r,\theta)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}\times [0;\pi]$.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Oleg, you have misunderstood me. The Radon transform $R(\cdot)$ is an operator which takes in certain functions $f$ and outputs certain functions $R(f)$. Until you tell me what $f$ are acceptable inputs for $R(\cdot)$ -- in other words, what the domain of $R(\cdot)$ is -- we cannot talk meaningfully about the range nor the inverse of the Radon transform

Comment: So for instance, I can see that $R(f)$ is well-defined if $f$ is continuous and compactly supported on ${\mathbb R}^2$. But are there more general functions whose Radon transforms you wish to consider?

Comment: Yemon, thanks for clarification. The domain of the considered Radon transform is all functions, such that for all $r$ and $\theta$ integral in (1) converges. One can easily prove, that $R^{-1}g$ belongs to the domain (function $g$ is defined in the last paragraph).

Comment: Actually, no. If you define the domain to be all functions for which the integral (1) converges, your "well known theorem" is false. The Radon and inverse Radon transforms establishes a bijection between Schwarz functions on R^2 and with Schwarz functions on $S^1 \times R$ that satisfies the homogeneous polynomial condition its moment. See chapter 1 of Helgason's book http://www-math.mit.edu/~helgason/Radonbook.pdf See also Dirk's answer below. So most likely when you take the inverse transform of you function, you get something that decays only slightly faster than $|x|^{-2}$. 

Comment: Ugh, I meant $|x|^{-1}$. Hit the wrong key by accident. 

Comment: Willie, thank you very much for the comment and for the link. Am I right, that your point is: if the domain is "all functions for which the integral (1) converges" then $g$ might not be equal to $R[R^{−1}g]$?

Comment: No, if $g$ is such that $R^{-1}$ is well defined and $R^{-1}g$ is such that $RR^{-1}g$ is well defined, $RR^{-1}g = g$ by definition. The problem is that $R: \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2) \to \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{P})$ with the image being functions satisfying the homogeneous polynomial condition, while $R$ may still send a bigger space (say, a space of functions for which the trace on all lines are defined and absolutely integrable) to something else. For comparison, think of the Fourier transform. It is a bijection of Schwarz functions, but it also is a bijection of $L^2$ function with itself. 

Comment: Hello, Willie, thanks for clarification. However, I am quite confused with it (see update in the question). It turned out, that $RR^{-1}g$ can not be equal to $g$. What is your opinion about it?

Comment: The last integral does not converge. 

Comment: Willie, I just found an example such that $R^{-1}(R g)$ does not equal $g$. The authors prove that there is a non-zero function such that its Radon transform is zero. So my question is, why do you claim that $RR^{-1}g=g$ for any $g$, such that $R^{-1}g$ and $RR^{-1}g$ are well-defined? How one can prove it? Thans a lot! The link to the paper: www.ams.org/journals/proc/1993-117-01/S0002-9939-1993-1106177-3/S0002-9939-1993-1106177-3.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Probably you refer to some theorem in "Mathematics of Computerized Tomography" by Frank Natterer (e.g. Theorem 4.2)? Then you are assuming that the domain in $\mathcal{S}$ and if I remember correctly, in that book this denotes the Schwartz space of rapidly decaying $C^\infty$-functions. Hence you paradox is resolved by the fact that $R^{-1} g$ is not a Schwartz function.

Comment: Hello Dirk! Thanks for this explanation. But anyway, it is easy to see, that one can apply a Radon transform to function $R^{-1}g$ and $RR^{-1}g$ is defined correctly. What is your opinion, is $RR^{-1}g$ equal to $g$ (see update of the question)? Thanks! 